# Definite integral $\int_1^{\pi/8}(x-1)\sin 4x\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I know, it might be silly, but I can't figure out what to do with $\sin 4x$ in

> $$\int_1^{\frac{\pi}{8}} (x-1)\sin 4x\,dx$$

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv50V.jpg)

I guess $u = x - 1$ and $\sin 4x=2\sin 2x\cos 2x$. But what's next? 
Thank you!

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\int (x-1)\sin (4x)\,dx=\int x \sin (4x)\,dx-\int  \sin (4x)\,dx$$ $$\int x \sin (4x)\,dx=\frac 14\int (4x)\sin(4x)\,dx=\frac 1{16}\int y\sin(y)\,dy $$ Now, integrate by parts.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for not using Integration by Parts from the start itself

Comment: @labbhattacharjee. Absolutely no reason !

Answer (score 0):

Integrate by parts,

$$\int(x-1)\sin4x\ dx=(x-1)\int\sin4x\ dx-\int\left(\dfrac{d(x-1)}{dx}\cdot\int\sin4x\ dx\right)dx$$

Comment: Still can't understand how to handle sin4x

Comment: @YannZRieneuf, $$\dfrac{d(\cos mx)}{dx}=?$$

Answer (score 0):

To begin, let us find the antiderivative by integration by parts. If we allow $u = x - 1$ and $dv = \sin\left(4x\right)dx,$ it follows that $du = dx$ and $v = -\frac{1}{4}\cos\left(4x\right).$ We continue as follows:
$$\int\left(x - 1\right)\sin\left(4x\right)dx$$
$$= -\frac{1}{4}\left(x - 1\right)\cos\left(4x\right) - \int-\frac{1}{4}\cos\left(4x\right)dx$$
$$= -\frac{1}{4}\left(x - 1\right)\cos\left(4x\right) + \frac{1}{16}\sin\left(4x\right) + C.$$

Now we evaluate the definite integral by finding the difference in the values of the antiderivative at $x = \frac{\pi}{8}$ and $x = 1.$ The answer is approximately $\boxed{0.110}.$